# PHP SOAP webservice call with two way SSL authentication

Tags: php, ssl, curl, soap, mutual-authentication

I am using curl API to call a SOAP web service with two SSL authentication and uses UserName,PasswordDigest and Nounce in SOAP headers .

curl API code is:

```
$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            "WEBSERVICE_URL" );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        1000);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1');
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, '1');
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'secret');
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, 'PEM');
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,"C:/XP/Projects/setups/certs/key.pem");
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $in);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($in) ));
$out = curl_exec($soap_do);
if($out === false)
{
echo "err";
$err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
curl_close($soap_do);
echo $err;
return $err;
}
else
{
echo "response ==";
echo $out;
echo "execu";
curl_close($soap_do);
return 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

CACERTS are already set in php.ini file:

Response is always Policy Falsified, can anybody please review that SSLKEY is properly set and outbound POST message will be encrypted with this key?

Full Response is:

```
response ==<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
        <soapenv:Code>
            <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Receiver</soapenv:Value>
        </soapenv:Code>
        <soapenv:Reason>
            <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Policy Falsified</soapenv:Text>
        </soapenv:Reason>
        <soapenv:Role>REMOVED FOR PRIVACY</soapenv:Role>
        <soapenv:Detail>
            <l7:policyResult status="Bad Request" xmlns:l7="http://www.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>
        </soapenv:Detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
execu*   Trying 216.178.233.150...
* Connected to impl.client.com (216.178.233.150) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/Project_ah/php/cacert.pem
CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=Maryland; L=Baltimore; O=Centers for Medicare & Medicaid Services; OU=OIS; CN=REMOVED FOR PRIVACY
*    start date: 2014-12-31 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-01-23 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: REMOVED FOR PRIVACY
*    issuer: C=US; O=Symantec Corporation; OU=Symantec Trust Network; CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /Imp1/servie HTTP/1.1
Host: REMOVED FOR PRIVACY
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2517
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 746
< Date: Wed, 03 Jun 2015 03:53:13 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

Note: Not using SOAPClient because it fails in parsing WSDL due to nested XSDs defining namespaces again

Comment: You ever get this to work?

Comment: @Saeven no switched to java for this call.

Comment: I am having the same issue...